# MERN, Mongoose: I randomized an array and saved it to Mongo, but I have to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

Tournament app.

When users sign up they are stored in `Tournament.participants` array.

When Tournament starts, all users in `Tournament.participants` are randomized and pushed to `Tournament.bracket.players`

Route that handles this:

```
router.post('/:id/shuffle-players', (req, res) => {
    const shuffleParticipants = array => {
        let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;   
        while(0 !== currentIndex) {
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;  
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }   
        return array;
    };

    Tournament.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id)
        .then(tournament => {
            if(!tournament) res.status(404).json({ msg: "Cannot find this tournament" });
            else {
                const { participants } = req.body;
                const { players } = tournament.bracket;

                if(players.length !== participants.length) {
                    const shuffledPlayers = shuffleParticipants(participants);
                    shuffledPlayers.forEach(player => {
                        players.push(player);
                    });
                };
                return tournament.save();
            };
        })
        .then(savedTournament => res.json(savedTournament))
        .catch(err => res.json(err));
});
```

The players are shuffled in random order, and this is displayed properly on the front end.

The problem is, when the component first renders, the `Tournament.bracket.players` are displayed in the original order.

This is odd because this suggests the component is rendering BEFORE the Post request, but this can't be, because `Tournament.bracket.players` is empty before the request, so the component should break.

I have to refresh the page to actually have them randomized.

This is a MERN app with Redux, I can post the reducer/action logic but I don't know if that's an issue here.

Component:

```
export const HostUI = ({ tournament }) => {
    const { players } = tournament.bracket;

    return (
        <div style={{color:"lightgrey"}}>
            <h1>Host UI</h1>
            {
                players && players.map(player => (
                    <div>
                        {player.username}
                    </div>
                ))
            }
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but in my opinion it makes more sense to handle the shuffling on the front end rather than the backend.

Comment: yeah, i'm close to giving up.  I got up this morning to do exactly what you said, since the component was actually working (I refactored some stuff based on your advice in my other post) and it worked fine.  Now, the component itself is bugging, giving me two problems instead of the original one.  
I'm ready to pay you to be a consultant or something.